# How does the following multiplication work?

Tags: javascript

I could not understand the following:

```
3 * { valueOf: function(){ return 5} }
//outputs 15
```

When I try to use like this:

```
3 * { 5 }
//syntax-error

3 * {valueOf: 5}
//outputs NaN
```

So, how exactly is this working with `{}` ?

Comment: `valueOf` is a function that is called when the object is converted to a number. The result of the conversion is the return value of the function. (your object is an object literal in your case.) If you don't provide such a function, it won't be converted to a number. (In the second case, you don't have an object literal, you have a syntax error, and in the 3rd case, your `valueOf` member is not a function, hence it cannot be called.)

Comment: You are overwriting the [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) function with a function of your own. This function gets called automatically to change convert an object to a primitive. The second case is a syntax error, and the third you aren't supplying a function.

Comment: sorry I'm not understanding 3 * {} ...

Comment: Get a good resource and look valueOf up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Because it's a weird construct. When there is a valueOf function in that object that you are multiplying by, it is called to decide what the 3 is then multiplied by

Comment: @epascarello I'm extremely sorry that I couldn't understand even from that reference...

Answer (score 5):

The difference is between `valueOf` being a function that returns a number, or simply being a number. [The `valueOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) must be a function on the object, so the numeric version isn't used.

The spec talks about how `valueOf` is supposed to work in [section 8.12.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8), stating that it must be callable to be considered while attempting to convert the object:

> 3. Let valueOf be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "valueOf".
> 4. If IsCallable(valueOf) is true then,
>
>    1. Let val be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of valueOf, with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
>    2. If val is a primitive value, return val.

This does not seem to have any case where `x.valueOf` is not callable, which is why your `{valueOf: 5}` example doesn't work.

Your first case (`3 * { 5 }`) is a syntax error, but even if you had a valid object on the right side, wouldn't work as [section 11.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5) of the spec attempts to convert the right operand to a number, unless you define a `valueOf` method which returns something that can be converted.

Note that `3 * { valueOf: function(){ return "5"} }` works just fine, as `"5"` can be run through [`toNumber`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) just fine (following normal coercion rules).

Comment: Sorry, but not understanding how multiplication is working.. alternative to this would be what? so i could understand...

Comment: There is no alternative. This is why it works when you define a `valueOf` method, because the VM is looking for and calling that method as part of applying the multiplication operator (see section 11.5, step 4).

Comment: `3 * { valueOf: function(){ return 5} }.valueOf()` also works, I think valueOf is automatically invoked in `3 * { valueOf: function(){ return 5} }` ???

Comment: Correct. You can invoke `valueOf` yourself, which leaves you with `3 * 5` (which can simply be multiplied). If you do not, the spec states that the VM must check for a `valueOf` method and call it, then pass the result to the `toNumber` function. The final value, after those two functions have been called, is used for the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

`valueOf` is a special attribute on objects. When an object has a `valueOf` attribute that is a function, that function is called to get the literal value of the object.

In your example, you are making `valueOf` a literal of 5, which is not a function that can be called by javascript